# How to duplicate display on external monitor?

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, monitor

I have connected my Dell Inspiron laptop with Lubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa OS to an external monitor through HDMI port. But the `xrandr` does not seem to recognize it. It says `HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`. I also checked for additional drivers and the software sources interface lists none to be installed.

Comment: The Lubuntu manual page on monitor setup can be found at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.10/monitor_settings.html where I'd use the fast menu to setup, however I suspect your issue is your external monitor is not recognized. With Inspiron laptops before (broken internal display) I've used the fn-display keys on the laptop to toggle internal/external/shared because the internal display didn't work at all (I needed to use external only) but your model inspiron may differ to models I've used that feature with (it worked with Lubuntu too)

Comment: In your case I'd likely first boot another OS (in 'live' mode) to ensure you cable setup works (esp. if using [passive] converter cables to connect display), or check your cable connections.  If it works on another system (same cables) then it's just a Lubuntu/linux settings issue...

Comment: I used Kubuntu live mode and the display was duplicated to external monitor perfectly. I ended up replacing Lubuntu with Kubuntu.